# how to rotate a image bitmap in java

Tags: java, bitmap, render

I have an `int` array that contains the information of colours to render an image. I want to rotate the image, but I can't find a way to do it.

```
public class Bitmap {

    public int w, h;
    public int[] pixels;

    public Bitmap(int w, int h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        pixels = new int[w * h];
    }

    public void clear(int color) {
        Arrays.fill(pixels, color);
    }


    public void render(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
        int x0 = x;
        int x1 = x + bitmap.w;
        int y0 = y;
        int y1 = y + bitmap.h;
        if (x0 < 0) x0 = 0;
        if (y0 < 0) y0 = 0;
        if (x1 > w) x1 = w;
        if (y1 > h) y1 = h;
        int ww = x1 - x0;
        for (int yy = y0; yy < y1; yy++) {
            int tp = yy * w + x0;
            int sp = (yy - y) * bitmap.w + (x0 - x);
            tp -= sp;
            for (int xx = sp; xx < sp + ww; xx++) {
                int col = bitmap.pixels[xx];
                if (col < 0) pixels[tp + xx] = col;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: by rotation do you mean 90 degrees? in which direction? do you want to change the data-source (the `pixels` array), or just the rendering? what is your rendering function supposed to do? is it relevant toe the question?

Comment: @hoijui i want to rotate it 90 degrees clock wise and counter clockwise and i don't wish to change the the pixel array.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order you access your array.

Comment: i dont realy know how i would acces so it would work could u maybe give a exmaple or hint?

Comment: You don't know how to do because your code is very poor written.
Using names like `x0` is completely wrong.
Using this logic `if (x0 < 0) x0 = 0;` is wrong because it should be replaced with max(int, int).
Starts with using a valid naming convention and after that it should be more easy access to the matrix in one order instead of another one.